# How to include two servlet in one jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a `.jsp` page in which I have written the following includes for two servlets. The URL for the Servlets are

```
<jsp:include page="/GetAllDetailsOfFollowing" ></jsp:include><br>
<jsp:include page="/GetAllTweetsOfFollowing" ></jsp:include><br>
```

When I am running this `.jsp` page on the server then it is only executing first servlet and it is not executing the second servlet. I cannot think what to do.

Comment: Can some one help me to solve this problem

Comment: I tried something like that and it worked. Maybe a problem in one of your servlets

Comment: why do you want to include servlets in jsp . poor design please read separation of concerns

Comment: Actually I am using MVC1. Here I am calling servlet which will forward to a jsp and that JSP will print some table. The other jsp is also doing same thing. I should not make connection on the jsp that's why I am doing so. And basiccly I want to bring all table on the same pages.

Comment: You can't include a servlet that only has a doPost method. Needs a doGet

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of things that you can do....

1. Check for your `URL` mappings, for their validity. If they are not valid change them to valid `URL`'S.
2. Check if both the servlets have a `doGet()` method. You cannot include a servlet that only has a `doPost()` method.